# Using batch for-loop, how to select from a list of elements an element composed of several names separated by space?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

From a list of elements, through a for-loop, I can select an element. Here is an example.

```
SET _list=Desktop Downloads Images Links

FOR %%k in (%_list%) DO (
    ECHO FolderName=%%k
)
PAUSE
```

Everything works if each item on the list consists of only one word. Below is an output example:

```
FolderName=Desktop
FolderName=Downloads
FolderName=Images
FolderName=Links
```

If the list item consists of two words separated by a space, I have some problems.

This is an example using **double quotes**:

```
SET _list=Desktop Downloads Images Links "Saved Games"
```

Output:

```
FolderName=Desktop
FolderName=Downloads
FolderName=Images
FolderName=Links
FolderName="Saved Games"
```

This is an example using **single quotes**:

```
SET _list=Desktop Downloads Images Links 'Saved Games'
```

Output:

```
FolderName=Desktop
FolderName=Downloads
FolderName=Images
FolderName=Links
FolderName='Saved
FolderName=Games'
```

How do I select an element composed of several names separated by a space?

I'd like to get something like this:

```
FolderName=Saved Games
```

Comment: Simple solution if you read the help for the `FOR` command. `ECHO FolderName=%%~k` From the help: **In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")**

Comment: It works. I read the `for` help but I misinterpreted it. Thank you very much!